# Voltage regulator Current regulation

Tags: current-measurement, current-source, 7805

I want to understand the concept of current regulation in the circuit, In my research I came across the following link [Boosting Regulator Current for IC 78xx by MJ2955](http://www.eleccircuit.com/boosting-regulator-current-for-ic-78xx-by-mj2955/)
[image]

where in the circuit schematic in link above, the author claims he has obtained 12V,5A as output with 20V input voltage.

I tried to simulate the same circuit but with input of 12V, 0.1A and 7805 regulator as shown in this schematic:
[image]

I see that when input current is 0.1A the output is 94mA approx. which agrees with ohms law V = I*R  = 94.086mA * 53.33 ohm = 5.01V

But when I have my input current as 0.06A the output voltage is 3V (why not 5V? )and current is 57mA, as shown in this schematic
[image]

This also agrees with ohms law V = I*R = 57.267 mA*53.33 ohm = 3.05V

The results are same as the circuit without the PNP transistor.
schematic:
[image]

So what is the impact of the PNP transistor in the circuit?
How can I boost the current in my circuit?
If I want to see 5W output across my load(53.33ohm in the schematic) what are the changes I should make in the circuit?

Note: I assume capacitors are only for smoothing the input and output and does not have much effect in simulation (correct me if wrong). I tried with 470uF in all three cases the results were same. (sorry was bit lazy to copy new screenshots and  I didnt have enough reputation to embed schematics in my question)

Comment: please copy links and paste to view schematics, sorry did not have enough reputation to embed links

Comment: The PNP *allows* the circuit to handle more current. It can't pull more current out of its supply than the supply is willing to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any linear voltage regulator (current boosted or not current boosted) you are going to get this: -

Output current = Input current - a few mA to power the regulator

You are never (ever) going to see an output current greater than the input current. If you want that then you must consider a buck voltage regulator.

> So what is the impact of the PNP transistor in the circuit? How can I
>   boost the current in my circuit? If I want to see 5W output across my
>   load(53.33ohm in the schematic) what are the changes I should make in
>   the circuit?

If you want 53.33 ohms to dissipate 5 watts then the voltage needed is governed by the formula: -

Power = \$V^2\div R\$ or

Voltage = \$\sqrt{P\cdot R}\$ = 16.329 volts

> I tried to simulate the same circuit but with input of 12V, 0.1A and
>   7805 regulator

The 7805 produces 5V on its output and not 16.329 volts.

Comment: I have my input current as 0.06A the output voltage is 3V (why not 5V? )

Comment: You can't cheat ohm's law (that easily). V=IR, so 0.06 x 53.33 = 3.2V. Now take into account that a little of that 0.06A is lost to the 7805 and doesn't flow through the load and it all works out...

Comment: So what does the article http://www.eleccircuit.com/boosting-regulator-current-for-ic-78xx-by-mj2955/ mean boosting current for 78XX?

Comment: A 78xx can only output a maximum of about 1A but if you need a regulated voltage, 3 amp supply you need to add components to it (or around it) so that the 3A is possible.

Comment: @SristiSravan, the usual way to supply a 7805 is with a fixed voltage supply. You are supplying it with a fixed current supply. The 12 V supply in your model has no effect because it's in series with the current supply. Your model is trying to predict the results of a gross abuse of the 7805.

Comment: @SristiSravan, when we say a "12 V 5 A" supply we normally mean a fixed voltage supply of 12 V, capable of producing anywhere from 0 to 5 A. What you modeled is a fixed current supply of 0.1 and 0.06 A.